# How can I make my table view look more like the one in the iOS Settings app?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

Take this table view for example - it has grey areas between its cells, unlike my table view that is all white and has separator lines even though there are no cells.

Also, the headers' title font is thinner and grayer than the cell text.

Keep in mind I'm making a table view programmatically.

Comment: You want a Grouped table view instead of Plain.

Answer (score 5):

`UITableViewStyle.Grouped` is what you are looking for! You can either set it in storyboard or when initializing the `UITableView` / `UITableViewController`.

Comment: You will also need to look into the tableView's header and footer views for sections.

Comment: how can you add text to the gray area?

Comment: take a look at this datasource method: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614850-tableview

Comment: I'm a bit lost...I know how to use titleForHeader...but I thought this grouped gray area is something else

Comment: in your screenshot there are four visible sections ("message list" (4 rows), "messages" (2 rows), "threading" (3 rows), "composing" (n rows)). you can implement those header titles with the method i provided.